# New Teams Client not set as default App for Meetings on a fresh Machine which never had MS Teams (old) installed

Tags: file-association, default-settings, microsoft-teams

On a fresh machine which never had the old teams installed the default setting for joining a meeting seems not to be set. The User has a roaming profile and had previously installed the old MS Teams client. But the old MS Teams client was only installed on the "old PC" of the user.

The User now gets this message when he want to join a Meeting, clicking the link in Outlook (see attached image)

[image]

How can this setting be set Domain Wide for all users?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this lines to the Fileassociation XML:

```
<Association Identifier="im" ProgId="AppX6pwygraeddkpp6m3wt43c7mpk6xm5tr2" ApplicationName="Microsoft Teams (work or school)" />
<Association Identifier="msteams" ProgId="AppXsz2w8kr3vqa5h0xgxy7bdt9816yyqntm" ApplicationName="Microsoft Teams (work or school)" />
<Association Identifier="msteamscanary" ProgId="AppXf0gv96f6b0d4mpph15j15n30wrwxk172" ApplicationName="Microsoft Teams (work or school)" />
```

Looks good now.